# New value to dropdown of product attribute is ignored : Magento 2.1

Tags: product, magento-2.1, import

While uploading new product, if attribute value of dropdown is not mathces with existing dropdown  values then it is getting ignored, it needs manual effort . 
What approach should take to achieve it programmatically ?[image]

Comment: you can set new product value inside csv to set value of attribute

Comment: You have to just create csv file for sku and attribute name to set value for all product attribute

Comment: we want to update with a module , so that non technical person can handle the process we want an attribute-upload module, where new attribute value  can be inserted into the same table.